# how to get correct x y coordinates programatically of view in ios 7?

Tags: ios7

I have used the following code to get the (x,y) coordinates of a view in ios 6
my code is:
`CGPoint point = [[MYView superview] superview].frame.origin;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]);
    NSLog(@"%f",point.y);`

how to get x,y coordinate in ios 7?

Comment: Are you sure that `[MYView superview] superview]` returns the same view in iOS7?